# From ansi encoding to utf8 (and hex bytes)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have some texts encoded in ansi windows codepage. It is known which codepage it is.

The data is stored in text files.

I would like to do the following:

- convert the to utf-8
- print the resulting utf-8 as bytes

Did read [python encoding guide](https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/), but I could not get the answer.

So, take the minimum example here:

```py
import codecs

chinaAnsi = '\xCE\xD2'    # 我  in chinese GBK    CJK Unified Ideograph-6211
                          # 0xE6 0x88 0x91   in UTF8

print(chinaAnsi.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
# results in b'\xc3\x8e\xc3\x92'  or ÎÒ
# which is meaningless.
# --> utf-8 representation of \xCE\xD2 in LATIN-1  (windows cp1252)
```

As can be seen from above, the cross coding works, my machine is Windows CP1252. *Except*  my input is in codepage 936.

So how do I deal with ansi input that is not from my own codepage ?

My final desired output from the minimal example would be the string in utf-8 followed by the utf-8 bytes.

```
我;e68891
```

The conversion of the string would mimic `iconv -f cp936 -t utf-8  theInput > theOutput`

Answer (score 0):

> I have some texts encoded in ansi windows codepage. It is known which codepage it is.
>
> The data is stored in text files.

Assuming the known codepage is cp936, read the files using that encoding and write them back out as UTF-8.  Example:

```
with open('input.txt', encoding='cp936') as fin:
    data = fin.read()

with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fout:
    fout.write(data)
```

Starting with your example bytes:

```py
>>> x = b'\xce\xd2'.decode('cp936')  # Gives '我'
>>> print(f"{x};{x.encode('utf8').hex()}")
我;e68891
```